# Is Siri Kit present for mac os apps?

Tags: macos, siri, sirikit

All the docs for Siri Kit refer to watchos and ios apps. Is it supported for mac os app development?
Additionally one of the first things to do for siri is to add the capability to your app. Unfortunately for mac os app I could not find any such capability.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

SiriKit is supported as of macOS 12, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit

Answer (score 0):

According to the SiriKit documentation, it's supported under iOS, watchOS, and macOS Catalyst.

As of current releases (10.15) of macOS, there's no direct access to SiriKit with a non-Catalyst app.

[SiriKit Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit)

Comment: so I can make a ipad app with sirikit and port it to macOs ?

Comment: Mac support is disabled in case of a Catalyst App